# Can quartz share same JOB between different nodes in clustered environment?

Tags: java, spring, jakarta-ee, quartz-scheduler

I am using Quartz in my Spring web application.

I successfully configured everything in cluster environment where quartz will pick its JOBS firing properly.

Now one of my JOB is big and will take so much resource and time. So can i share the JOB between nodes so that same JOB is executed on two nodes in a clustered way, Not different triggers ?

Or there any other ways to achieve this ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Quartz provides feature to trigger jobs. What you do inside in not quartz's responsibility.

Depending upon what your job is doing you can look to divide into smaller jobs and then cluster will help.

If you provide more info then we can help.

Comment: We have service layer class which takes reading from millions of meters and update DB. So what I am doing now is calling this service layer class from my quartz JOB. So this is big JOB, We want this to be shared between nodes but cannot split in to smaller JOB classes.

Comment: We have service layer class which gets reading from millions of devices and store in DB. I am calling this service layer from our Quartz JOB. But the the issue is one node alone is not able to handle this load. So is it possible to share the same JOB between multiple nodes ?

Comment: How you get the millions of job? Is it in some file?